# Android Toolbar Title shows White background in title

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I am bit confused why this is happening in my app. i just set toolbar title and it shows white background color under the title. i attached an image and code as example.

[image: Toolbar title]

Here is my code i am trying.

**xml file**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    app:title="Toolbar Title"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" // i also tried without this line
    app:popupTheme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"/>  // i also tried without this line
```

**Main Activity**

```
private fun initToolbar() {
    val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar?>(R.id.toolbar)
    toolbar?.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar?.title = "Toolbar Title"
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    // Tools.setSystemBarColor(this)
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

[image]

**style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: `Theme.Holo` – Why are you using `Holo` themes there? Those are ancient, and I wouldn't be surprised if that has something to do with your issue.

Comment: i also tried without any theme but still same issue.

Comment: What do you have set for the `theme` for that `<activity>`? Or, for the `<application>`, if there's not one on the `<activity>`?

Comment: i updated the question with manifest and style code

Comment: What's the `parent` in the `AppTheme` `<style>`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your theme should have some **parent**, for example:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.Light">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

check this out for more information
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes